# Is there a way to suppress the Y/N dialog for "remove all breakpoints"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I have a button in my tool bar to remove all of the breakpoints.  When I press it, it prompts to ask if I really want to do this.  I would like to suppress that behavior, and just silently remove all of the break points.

Is there a setting, workaround, technique that would allow this?

Thanks.

Evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Go to Options in the Tools menu and expand the Debugging tree node on the left hand side.

The first checkbox uder 'General' is 'Ask before deleting all breakpoints'